# How to control specific text selection in a TextArea (JavaFX)?

Tags: javafx, controls, textarea, selection

I'm using JavaFX and have a TextArea. In the textArea I need some way to ensure the user may only select one line at a time. So for my delete button what I have so far is:

```
deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> { 
    String s = "DELETE: ";
    s += receipt.getSelectedText();
    receipt.replaceSelection(s); 
});
```

How can I enforce that user can only select one full line at a time? Each line will have \n as a breaker, so I was thinking I can some how use it as a key. An issue is the users ability to select more than one line at a time or a partial line. And yes, I must use textArea. I have right now where the delete button is reading what got deleted and displays it. The readt of my code is working great with this one issue. I have about 15 classes that all take in textAreas as a parameter where, when a button is clicked, it appends it to the TextArea and then it saves it to a specified object as a certain attribute. I just need highlight control, or a way to added a checkbox or a way to read where the user clicks that highlights the entire row (but if the click somewhere else, it highlights/selects that line, or try to highlight themselves, it doesn't let them).

Comment: Hmm. "I have 15 classes that all take in `TextArea`s as a parameter..." This is a *really* bad design. You should separate the data you are presenting (a collection of strings, or lines of text, etc) from the actual presentation of the data (the text area, or whatever control is appropriate). The problem (as you are discovering) is that if you find you want to change the presentation - e.g. use a list view instead of a text area -, you can't, because the API for your logic relies on a particular UI. It is far better to refactor and fix this *now* than to continue to invest in a bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter in a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to intercept and modify changes to the selection.

Here is a quick example. You could also modify the change to actually effect the functionality you are looking for on delete as well.

```
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaSelectByLine extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        UnaryOperator<Change> filter = c -> {

            int caret = c.getCaretPosition();
            int anchor = c.getAnchor() ;

            if (caret != anchor) {
                int start = caret ;
                int end = caret ;
                String text = c.getControlNewText();
                while (start > 0 && text.charAt(start) != '\n') start-- ;
                while (end < text.length() && text.charAt(end) != '\n') end++ ;
                c.setAnchor(start);
                c.setCaretPosition(end);
            }

            return c ;
        };
        TextFormatter<String> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(filter);
        textArea.setTextFormatter(formatter);

        Scene scene = new Scene(textArea, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```